# Android Studio - Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin' - Failed to transform artifact 'x86_debug.jar

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, kotlin

I've followed all instruction in this page: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

but when I'm trying to run the "first_app" I get an error:

> Android Studio - run first_app

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

ERROR

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'x86_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\m-err\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c\e05f5680b1bbc2a38b625423c4ab890a526847cc\x86_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\m-err\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c\e05f5680b1bbc2a38b625423c4ab890a526847cc\x86_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: invalid stored block lengths. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
   > Failed to transform artifact 'x86_64_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\m-err\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_64_debug\1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c\35b1d03b15670cc489efdcf317faf29bfd904402\x86_64_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\m-err\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_64_debug\1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c\35b1d03b15670cc489efdcf317faf29bfd904402\x86_64_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: invalid stored block lengths. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**flutter doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): 
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.18362.720], locale it-IT)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
```

**build.gradle (android)***

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### build.gradle (app/src)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.first_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

---

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

---

#### TESTS

1. updated kotlin version
2. flutter clean --> D:\Development\flutter\first_app
3. recreate the project after updates

#### LOGFILE

```
    2020-04-01 15:38:00,597 [  96871]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'D:\Development\flutter\first_app' first_appKotlin2JvmCompilerArguments took 11 ms 
2020-04-01 15:38:43,068 [ 139342]   INFO - .flutter.run.daemon.FlutterApp - RunApp first_app (Run) 
2020-04-01 15:38:43,068 [ 139342]   INFO - .flutter.run.daemon.FlutterApp - D:\Programs\flutter\bin\flutter.bat [--no-color, run, --machine, --track-widget-creation, --device-id=emulator-5554, lib\main.dart] 
2020-04-01 15:38:58,491 [ 154765]   INFO - .FlutterAppDaemonEventListener - app shutdown took longer than 100ms 
2020-04-01 15:38:58,516 [ 154790]   INFO - .flutter.run.daemon.FlutterApp - StopApp first_app (Run) 
2020-04-01 15:38:58,958 [ 155232]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2020-04-01 15:38:59,037 [ 155311]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 2ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-04-01 15:38:59,073 [ 155347]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 36ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-04-01 15:38:59,073 [ 155347]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 3 files to update 
2020-04-01 15:38:59,112 [ 155386]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 39ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-04-01 15:39:48,894 [ 205168]   WARN - n.process.BaseOSProcessHandler - Process hasn't generated any output for a long time.
If it's a long-running mostly idle daemon process, consider overriding OSProcessHandler#readerOptions with 'BaseOutputReader.Options.forMostlySilentProcess()' to reduce CPU usage.
Command line: D:\Programs\Android\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_2_API_29 
java.lang.Throwable: Process creation:
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler.<init>(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:33)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler.<init>(EmulatorProcessHandler.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorRunner.start(EmulatorRunner.java:57)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.startAvd(AvdManagerConnection.java:419)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.startAvd(AvdManagerConnection.java:358)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.RunAvdAction.actionPerformed(RunAvdAction.java:36)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdUiAction.hyperlinkUpdate(AvdUiAction.java:127)
    at com.intellij.ui.HyperlinkLabel.fireHyperlinkEvent(HyperlinkLabel.java:218)
    at com.intellij.ui.HyperlinkLabel.processMouseEvent(HyperlinkLabel.java:141)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4532)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:878)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:823)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:704)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:465)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2020-04-01 15:58:25,798 [1322072]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - Set preferredFocusableComponent in 'Project' content in TODO tool window to avoid focus-related problems. 
2020-04-01 15:58:25,799 [1322073]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - Project tool window - parent container is hidden 
2020-04-01 15:58:45,410 [1341684]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - Set preferredFocusableComponent in '' content in Dart Analysis tool window to avoid focus-related problems. 
2020-04-01 15:58:45,410 [1341684]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl -  tool window - parent container is hidden 
2020-04-01 15:58:47,751 [1344025]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - Set preferredFocusableComponent in '' content in Logcat tool window to avoid focus-related problems. 
2020-04-01 15:58:47,751 [1344025]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl -  tool window - parent container is hidden 
2020-04-01 15:58:47,837 [1344111]   INFO - AndroidLogcatToolWindowFactory - Successfully obtained debug bridge 
2020-04-01 15:58:59,615 [1355889]   INFO - m.pty4j.windows.WindowsVersion - Windows version: 10.0.18362 
2020-04-01 15:59:04,985 [1361259]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - Set preferredFocusableComponent in 'Project' content in TODO tool window to avoid focus-related problems. 
2020-04-01 15:59:04,986 [1361260]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - Project tool window - parent container is hidden 
2020-04-01 15:59:05,402 [1361676]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - Set preferredFocusableComponent in 'main.dart' content in Run tool window to avoid focus-related problems. 
2020-04-01 15:59:05,402 [1361676]   WARN - j.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl - main.dart tool window - parent container is hidden 
2020-04-01 15:59:12,685 [1368959]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.GradleScriptInputsWatcher$Storage 
2020-04-01 15:59:12,693 [1368967]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.configuration.utils.ScriptClassRootsStorage 
2020-04-01 15:59:13,373 [1369647]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 734 ms 
2020-04-01 16:00:37,197 [1453471]   INFO - .flutter.run.daemon.FlutterApp - RunApp first_app (Run) 
2020-04-01 16:00:37,197 [1453471]   INFO - .flutter.run.daemon.FlutterApp - D:\Programs\flutter\bin\flutter.bat [--no-color, run, --machine, --track-widget-creation, --device-id=emulator-5554, lib\main.dart] 
2020-04-01 16:00:43,092 [1459366]   INFO - .FlutterAppDaemonEventListener - app shutdown took longer than 100ms 
2020-04-01 16:00:43,121 [1459395]   INFO - .flutter.run.daemon.FlutterApp - StopApp first_app (Run)
```

Please help me, I'm following a course but I cannot continue if I don't solve that.

\TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suspect this to be the result of a broken download or an interrupted transform, because the error message `invalid stored block lengths` clearly hints for a corrupt ZIP/JAR file. Try to empty directory `C:\Users\m-err\.gradle\caches` and then rebuild the application.

And do not disable Lint checks, so that it would complain about eventual invalid packages:

```
lintOptions {
    // disable 'InvalidPackage'
}
```

Also, when only using `androidx` dependencies, you don't need to use the Jetifier.

Comment: It works now, I love you!

Ok, I corrected the lintOptions.

I'm new on Flutter so I still have to learn many things.

I created the project with flutter from cmd: \flutter create first_app

so Jetifier is always enabled when I create a project, should I always go to disable it?

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

android.enableR8=true

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true --> false